# How do I make the subtitle columns display an Average when there's blank data in my Pivot Table?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I have data which I store in a table.

The data is experimental data, and it's set up such that data can be input into the source table and is displayed on the pivot table.

However, some experiments return with incomplete results, hence I have certain values which are blank in my source table and hence my pivot table.

Is there any way to make it such that the subtotals (which I've set up to display Averages) display? For example if there's 2 tests, one with a result of 25 and one with a blank result, can I set it up to display an Average of 25?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If the cells are really *blank* then `average()` will ignore them in its calculations. If, instead, they hold a `0`, until you put something else there, you will need to use the `averageifs()` function. Say you are doing the average for cells `B2` to `B50`, then you could use `averageifs(B2:B50,B2:B50,0)`